# Is it possible to loop over an array of Text views and display them?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an array of type `[Text]` that I'm trying to render using a `ForEach`, however it's telling me that `Text` needs to conform to `Hashable` or `Identifiable`. Is there a different way to accomplish this? I did try my hand at a Hashable implementation:

```swift
extension Text: Hashable {
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self)
    }
}
```

but this didn't work, unfortunately. I don't want to add the `Text` views because I want to control the spacing between them.

Comment: Rather than having an array of views, I would suggest that you have an array of the relevant *data* and then you iterate over that, producing `Text` views as you go.

Comment: Yes, you should create a [String] and within the ForEach, add each as a Text(String)

Comment: cool, that is what I ended up doing @Paulw11. If you want to submit an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I am a little surprised ForEach doesn't work with views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that technically it is possible (just to be honest)

```
struct Demo1: View {
    let texts = [Text("1"), Text("2"), Text("3"), Text("4")]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(texts.indices, id: \.self) { texts[$0] }
        }
    }
}
```

however, of course, by SwiftUI the correct is

```
struct Demo2: View {
    let texts = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(texts.indices, id: \.self) { Text(texts[$0]) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the Type of texts is [View] or [AnyView] in first way? I looked about does type says Array<Text>, so are working with Views with that array or AnyViews?

Answer (score 0):

Since SwiftUI is declarative, we only need to change data, to let swiftui update themselves. so that let your ui depend on data itself not on another ui thing.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let yourTexts = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(yourTexts, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```